# Journal Entries vs Entities - what should be the source of truth?

Tags: data-structures, reporting

So, this is going to sound like an accounting question, and on top of that *might* be a little too opinion or discussion-based for Stack Exchange. But we've been going back and forth on this a little bit so I'm curious to know what the dev community thinks.

If you're building an accounting system, obviously at some point you're going to need to put things into journal entries -- they're the standard tool that accountants use for building a picture of the current financial state of the business. You've also got other entities that are related to journal entries to help build that picture, things like invoices and expenses and so forth. In some sense this is duplicate data, because your entities should match what you have in your journal entries.

The question is: what should be the source of truth? The entity or the journal entry?

On the one hand, journal entries are difficult to do correctly -- I know we've struggled with them at FreshBooks -- so if you build your entity directly from journal entries, you can make sure that the entity amount and the journal entries always match.

On the other, journal entries are a very denormalized data structure from the entity perspective, because they're built for reporting. When you build entities out of journal entries, everything gets more complicated, not only basic CRUD but also things like paging and filtering and so forth. On that side they feel like an accounting-specific ETL, and it would otherwise be crazy talk to build your production systems based on your reporting tools.

How have you dealt with journal entries in the past? What kinds of tools have you built to make sure they're correct? (what would be an appropriate tag)

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in accounting, so maybe someone else will have input on that.

However, more broadly speaking, you're asking about several different kinds of responsibilities, and if we tease them apart a bit we might see a larger picture.

> In some sense this is duplicate data, because your entities should match what you have in your journal entries.

There are multiple sources of truth, but not for the same responsibilities.

Artifacts may be compiled into another form, perhaps such as journal entries.  Those compilations are then archived.  There is a business function that creates these compilations and is responsible for their accuracy, and, there is also a business function (possibly the same group) that has the responsibility as source of truth with respect to archival and retrieval.  Only official compilations get into the archive.  So, the collection of archived compilations is a responsibility and source of truth larger than the individual facts they came from.

As such, other compilations, say made by third parties and not in the archive, are not official.

This could apply to other fields as well.  For example, as a software company, you would archive both source code and released binaries.  Even though one can be generated from the other, particular release binaries are official.